# How can I Change collectionList Title?? "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1"

Tags: objective-c, error-code, phphotolibrary

I want to change the title of Photo Album.

So I tried

```
- (IBAction)reNameTitle:(id)sender {
PHAssetCollection *myCollection = [self.collectionArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

PHFetchResult *results = [PHCollectionList fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions:nil];

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHCollectionList *collectionList, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if ([collectionList.localizedTitle isEqualToString:myCollection.localizedTitle])
         {
             PHCollectionListChangeRequest *collectionChangeRequest = [PHCollectionListChangeRequest changeRequestForCollectionList:collectionList];
             collectionChangeRequest.title = @"newName";
             NSLog(@"collectionChangeRequest - %@", collectionChangeRequest);
             //This log result is ----- "collectionChangeRequest - <PHCollectionListChangeRequest: 0x170268480> title=newName hasAssetChanges=0"
         }
     }];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Finished editing collection. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
    //This log result is ----- "Finished editing collection. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)""
}];
```

}

First log is changed title "newName" but second log is "error CODE=-1" and my album title is not changing.
What is the problem in my code??

Answer (score 1):

```
    -(void)changeAlbumtitle:(PHAssetCollection *)collection withTitle:(NSString *)title {

    if (![collection canPerformEditOperation:PHCollectionEditOperationRename]) {

        NSLog(@"can't PerformEditOperation");
        return;
    }


    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *changeTitlerequest =[PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection];
        changeTitlerequest.title = title;


    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Finished editing collection. %@", (success ? @"Successfully." : error));
    }];


}
```

In Above give function pass the album object (PHAssetCollection ) and title

- First the function check PHAssetCollection can perform rename editOperation
- If edit operation is possible then implement PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest and set the new title.